# BIM 360 API - Forge App - getUsers returns "This account doesn't exist"

Tags: python, autodesk, forge

New to RESTful APIs here, so this may be a stupid question: I am trying to query all users in a BIM 360 account per the following link:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-GET/

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-python-tutorial

I am using the above repository by xiaodongliang as a starting point, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Get Users Failed! status = 404 ; message = {"code":1004,"message":"this account doesn't exist."}
```

Here is the list of changes I have made:

1. Changed the relevant information for my BIM 360 / Forge account within **config.py**
2. Added a module in **forge_da.py** for getUsers()
3. Modified getToken() accordingly so that **'scope': 'account:read'**

I have checked that each ID, token, and secret is correct, and I have added a Custom Integration into the BIM 360 Account. Not sure what I am missing here. See the added and changed modules below:

```
def getToken():
"""Obtain Forge token given a client id & secret"""
req = { 'client_id' : Forge_CLIENT_ID, 'client_secret': Forge_CLIENT_SECRET, 'grant_type' : 'client_credentials','scope':'account:read'}
resp = requests.post(Forge_BASE_URL+'/authentication/v1/authenticate', req)
if resp.status_code == 200:
    config.token = resp.json()['access_token']
    return config.token
else:
    print('Get Token Failed! status = {0} ; message = {1}'.format(resp.status_code,resp.text) )
    return None

def getUsers():
"""Query all BIM 360 Users in given Account"""
print(Forge_ACCOUNT_ID, config.token)
resp = requests.get(Forge_BASE_URL+'/hq/v1/accounts/:account_id/users', headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ config.token}, json={'account_id' : Forge_ACCOUNT_ID})
if resp.status_code == 200:
    config.users = resp.json()
    return config.users
else:
    print('Get Users Failed! status = {0} ; message = {1}'.format(resp.status_code,resp.text) )
    return None
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
Joseph Freund

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I found my error. I changed the following line:

```
resp = requests.get(Forge_BASE_URL+'/hq/v1/accounts/:account_id/users', headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ config.token}, json={'account_id' : Forge_ACCOUNT_ID})
```

to:

```
resp = requests.get(Forge_BASE_URL+'/hq/v1/accounts/' + Forge_ACCOUNT_ID + '/users', headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ config.token})
```

Posting the question forced me to actually look at it. Thanks for the help!